# Increment variable based on global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I want to do is the following code

```
$floorNo = 1; // current floor

if ($floorNo == 1){
  $number1++;
} else if ($floorNo == 2){
  $number2++;
} ...
```

etc.

Is there a shorter version, something like `($number+$floorNo)++;` ?

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you begin your variables with `$`? This isn't PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var floorNo = 1;
arr[floorNo]++; // = [1, 3, 3]
```

If `floorNo` is entered by the user, you can use the modulo operator to ensure it's valid:

```
arr[floorNo % arr.length]++; // = [1, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array for this task:

```
var $numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var $floorNo = parseInt(prompt("Enter number"), 10);

$numbers[$floorNo - 1]++; // `-1` as the array uses zero-based indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, whenever you have `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc. you should probably be using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead. For example:

```
$numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0];  // initialize your numbers

...    

$numbers[$floorNo - 1]++; // increment the number at the given 'floorNo'
```

Also note that arrays indexes typically start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval:

```
var $floorNo = 1,
    $number1 = 5;

try {
    eval('var $nValue = $number' + $floorNo.toString() + '++;');
    console.log(eval('$number' + $floorNo.toString()));
}
catch(e) {}
```

Be carefull. Because variables `$number1..N` must be defined before using eval.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but I still will stay with the array solution. Thanks!